# How to read/copy command prompt data using JAVA

Tags: java, file, cmd, process

I got an application that prints bunch of lines on the command prompt, I want to read that information and write it into a file to track my application output.

I can not invoke my application using `Process` or `ProcessBuldier` and read output because the output it prints uses a different process.

What I want to do is copy data from the prompt and paste it into a file, I just do not know how to access that process.

for example, open cmd prompt and type dir manually know I want to read that info and write it into a file(remember I am not using `getruntime.exec('cmd','\c',dir)` to  get my cmd output but instead I am doing dir part manually by opening cmd and typing all I am doing is reading the output.

Comment: What do you mean by "because the output it prints uses a different process"?

Comment: So the application(Tosca) runs through putty and prints the output on putty console, I currently manually copy my screen and paste it into a notepad.

Comment: so why don't you use another SSH client? JSch for instance http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ but any command-line program would do.

Answer (score 0):

basically what you want amounts to a keylogger. This has security implications (you might try to intercept someone's password) so I think it's not possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for manual steps to copy visible text from cmd, then following steps would help.

1. Right click on cmd.
2. Select "mark" from context menu.
3. Drag over the text that you want to copy.
4. Right click again to copy.
5. Paste anywhere you want.

Else please explain your question in more detail.

Comment: So the application(Tosca) runs through putty and prints the output on the `putty` console, I currently manually copy my screen and paste it into a notepad. But at times I have to run my application more than 20 times and each time I have to wait for output and copy paste it. So I made a java code to run my application but since my application invokes `putty`. All I want is access the putty console and copy the output through my program.

Comment: You can write a java program that starts Tosca as external process and get handle of iostream of that process. can you share the command that you fire on putty to start Tosca.